# Windows Phone 7 Consume Webservice JSON data

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, mobile

I am now just learning Windows Phone 7 development, I am using C#, as this is the language I am the most familiar with.

For now, I would like to create the following flow: user type something in a text field and press a button -> i show him a "Please wait" message box and send the text field text to a WebService (maybe over HTTPS), when the WebService response is received I will show him another screen, bases on the response data.

This WebService retrieves only JSON data, so I need to parse JSON data.

I think I am already able to send data and retrieve the response from the server, however, I dont know how to show this "loading" message box, hide it when dode, and start a new screen (blocking the access to this first one).

On button click:

```
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/");
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        wr.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), wr);
```

GetRequestStreamCallback method:

```
    void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = wr.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("key=" + someText.Text);
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        wr.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), wr);
    }
```

GetResponseCallback method:

```
    void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            MessageBox.Show(streamReader.ReadToEnd()); // ???
            streamReader.Close();
            streamResponse.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            // Does nothing
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever method you use for [progress indication](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/31-days-mango-day-15-progress), turn it on right before the call to the service, `myProgressIndicator.Show = true;` then in the callback and when done with any other processing, turn it off, `myProgressIndicator.Show = false;`.  Don't forget to turn it off in the catch for exception handling as well.

[Coding4Fun](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) has a progress overlay.